# Minimising risk in dynamical systems

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization, economics

I have been reading the paper of Goerner and Ulancowicz - "Quantifying economic sustainability" in which it is suggested that there is a tradeoff between sustainability and efficiency. Essentially, if we introduce lots of measures to maximise individual profit we in fact increase risk in the whole system. But I want to be able to quantify this! There is an efficiency which maximises the sustainability but I can't seem to find any resources which give an estimate of this efficiency in terms of the number of measures in place proportional to the size of the system.

Does anyone have any resources detailing this or any insight into how we could perhaps introduce a simple model of this?

Comment: Economics is most of the time guided by intuition rather than a measurable model.

Comment: @BrunoHenriquePeixoto: _Au contraire_, most economists do use mathematical models.  Unfortunately, Goerner and Ulancowicz are extremely heterodox.

Comment: https://images.app.goo.gl/7osTx1ATgf2FtkW5A